# Create your own class from a template with GTK4, C and XML

Tags: c, templates, gtk, builder, gtk4

I'm trying to test the example from the GNOME Developer Documentation.

https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials/widget-templates.html

But I seem to be doing something wrong, because I get the error message:

```
_myWidget:11427): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:16:35.255: Trying to snapshot GtkEntry 0x55ac0c7d7650 without a current allocation

(_myWidget:11427): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:16:35.255: Trying to snapshot GtkButton 0x55ac0c7b7b40 without a current allocation
```

widget-class.c

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

// own class with button and entry
// Add the template registration to your class_init function

G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE (ExampleWidget, example_widget, EXAMPLE, WIDGET, GtkWidget)

#define EXAMPLE_TYPE_WIDGET (example_widget_get_type ())   

struct _ExampleWidget
{
  GtkWidget parent_type;
  GtkWidget *entry;
  GtkWidget *button;
};

G_DEFINE_TYPE (ExampleWidget, example_widget, GTK_TYPE_WIDGET)

//Clear the template children when disposing the widget instance
static void
example_widget_dispose (GObject *gobject)
{
  gtk_widget_dispose_template (GTK_WIDGET (gobject), EXAMPLE_TYPE_WIDGET);
  G_OBJECT_CLASS (example_widget_parent_class)->dispose (gobject);
}

static void
example_widget_class_init (ExampleWidgetClass *klass)
{
  G_OBJECT_CLASS (klass)->dispose = example_widget_dispose;
  GtkWidgetClass *widget_class = GTK_WIDGET_CLASS (klass);
  gtk_widget_class_set_template_from_resource (widget_class,"/Prog/widget.ui");

  //Bind the widgets defined inside the template file to the corresponding 
  //members of the widget’s instance data structure
  gtk_widget_class_bind_template_child (widget_class, ExampleWidget, entry);
  gtk_widget_class_bind_template_child (widget_class, ExampleWidget, button);

}

//Initialize the template children when initializing the widgdet instance
static void
example_widget_init (ExampleWidget *self)
{
  gtk_widget_init_template (GTK_WIDGET (self));

  // It is now possible to access self->entry and self->button
}

static GtkWidget * example_widget_new(void)   
{
    ExampleWidget *widget = g_object_new(EXAMPLE_TYPE_WIDGET,NULL);
    return GTK_WIDGET(widget);   
} 

/****************************************************************/

static void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *window;

    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    //The example widget is created and installed here
    GtkWidget *widget_1 = example_widget_new();

    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window),GTK_WIDGET(widget_1));
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW (window));
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;
    app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.examplewidget", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate",G_CALLBACK(activate),NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);
    return status;
}
```

widget.ui

```
<interface>
  <template class="ExampleWidget" parent="GtkWidget">
    <child>
      <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry">
      </object>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkButton" id="button">
        <property name="label">Hello</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </template>
</interface>
```

resource.xml

```
<gresources>
        <gresource prefix="Prog">
                <file preprocess= "xml-stripblanks">widget.ui</file>
        </gresource>
</gresources>
```

Does anyone have any idea where the problem might be?

Comment: The path to the widget.ui file in gresource is relative to the gresource.xml file itself. Are your widget.ui and your gresource.xml in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, the two files are in the same directory. I've been working on the question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/71365107/22768315 where it works that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and trial and error, especially with the help of the question [Writing a Custom GTK widget with template UI files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77768792/22768315) I've found the solution. In the example I'm using, the layout manager is missing.
For this purpose, the following additions were necessary in the class_init function:

```
static void
example_widget_class_init (ExampleWidgetClass *klass)
{
 ...

  gtk_widget_class_set_layout_manager_type (widget_class, GTK_TYPE_BOX_LAYOUT); 

}
```

[image]